# Como meter un if cuando estoy generando un xml en c#

Tags: c#, xml, condiciones

No sé si esté bien formulada mi pregunta pero doy un ejemplo.

Estoy usando C# para generar un xml en base a una base de datos, todo esto ya lo tengo listo, lo llena y no tengo ningún error. Mi pregunta es la siguiente, y para que se entienda mejor voy a poner una parte del código que genera mi xml.

```
new XElement("documentosadjuntos",
 from docadjunto in DocumentosAdjuntos.GetDocumentosAdjuntos(NumeroDocumento, CodigoDocumento)
 select new XElement("documentoadjunto",
       new XElement("tipo_codigo", docadjunto.iTipoCodigo),
       new XElement("numero_documento", docadjunto.iNumeroDocumento),
       new XElement("fecha_documento", docadjunto.iFechaDocumento),
       new XElement("emisor", docadjunto.iEmisor),
       new XElement("aduana_origen_codigo", docadjunto.iAduanaOrigenCodigo),
       new XElement("rut_numero", docadjunto.iRutNumero),
       new XElement("rut_dv", docadjunto.iRutDV)
```

)//fin documentos adjunto

Ejemplo práctico: un cliente puede rellenar estos campos por medio de un formulario y hay veces en que, por ejemplo, no rellena lo que es el **emisor**. Hay alguna forma de poner un **if**? para ver si se incluye esta parte de código?

```
new XElement("emisor", docadjunto.iEmisor),
```

Porque si la persona no rellena el campo simplemente va a aparecer como vacio y mi idea es que no aparezca, puse este código pero visual me dice que no corresponde:

```
new XElement("documentosadjuntos",
from docadjunto in DocumentosAdjuntos.GetDocumentosAdjuntos(NumeroDocumento, CodigoDocumento)
select new XElement("documentoadjunto",
        new XElement("tipo_codigo", docadjunto.iTipoCodigo),
        new XElement("numero_documento", docadjunto.iNumeroDocumento),
        new XElement("fecha_documento", docadjunto.iFechaDocumento),
        if (docadjunto.iEmisor != "")
             {
             new XElement("emisor", docadjunto.iEmisor),
             } 
        new XElement("aduana_origen_codigo", docadjunto.iAduanaOrigenCodigo),
        new XElement("rut_numero", docadjunto.iRutNumero),
        new XElement("rut_dv", docadjunto.iRutDV))//fin documentos adjunto
     ),//fin documentosadjuntos
```

Creo que mi solución puede estar en el `from`, ¿hacer otro tipo de consulta?.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando insertar un bloque donde solo se aceptan expresiones, `if` es un bloque pero sí puedes hacerlo con el [operador condicional `?`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (también lo llaman operador ternario).  Este operador también evalua una condición pero es una expresión y devuelve un valor.  En este caso el constructor de `XElement` acepta que le pasen el valor `null` y lo que hace es simplemente ignorarlo:

```
new XElement("documentosadjuntos",
    from docadjunto in DocumentosAdjuntos.GetDocumentosAdjuntos(NumeroDocumento, CodigoDocumento)
    select new XElement("documentoadjunto",
        // ...
        new XElement("fecha_documento", docadjunto.iFechaDocumento),

        string.IsNullOrEmpty(docadjunto.iEmisor) ? null : docadjunto.iEmisor,

        new XElement("aduana_origen_codigo", docadjunto.iAduanaOrigenCodigo),
        // ...
     )
```

Comment: si conozco el operador ternario, lo uso harto en php pero no tenía idea de cómo se podía ocupar para este caso con c#. Muchas Gracias